# Making a new box for vagrant up

Tags: linux, centos, vagrant

So I have a vagrant instance that also calls the following scripts:

The base OS is centos

```
<TeamName>.sh    //does a preliminary set up for teams
ABashSetUp.sh     //writes to bashrc and bash_profile
BNuxeoSetUp.sh    //Sets up the standard base nuxeo package used by all teams
CGetSpark.sh      //Sets up spark 
DGetWars.sh      //Gets the war files needed for the teams.
```

Currently, vagrant up takes about 50-60 mins. Most of that time is taken up in the Nuxeo download script.

I was looking into creating a new "base machine" that is our OS with Nuxeo installed onto it. With vagrant up, it would proceed as before, but not do the BNuxeo step as the machine already comes with that.

Is there a way to do this? I am fairly new to vagrant and how it works so any advice is educational for me.

Comment: The standard way is [packer](https://www.packer.io/) with the [vagrant post-processer](https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/vagrant.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Packer](https://www.packer.io/) provides a simple interface to generate boxes for most common VM providers as well as AMIs for AWS, and more. This is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I would love to test this... but none of my shells are working due to some security updates.